# Android- ArrayAdapter in listview not refreshing

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I currently have a listview with utilizes an ArrayAdapter. I start off with no data and dynamically add data to it using user input. For some reason, when I call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` the list view does not refresh. I have for test purposes added some basic data before it and it does simply, therefore the adapter is working correctly. This is the first time implementing my own adapter so i am not sure if i am doing something wrong or not. Thanks. Code below.

My Adapter:

```
public class FeedListviewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FeedPostingLayout> {
    // add the feed posting layout
    ArrayList<FeedPostingLayout> postingLayout;

    public FeedListviewAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            ArrayList<FeedPostingLayout> postingLayout) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, postingLayout);
        this.postingLayout = postingLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = vi.inflate(R.layout.post_layout, null);
        }

        FeedPostingLayout layout = postingLayout.get(position);
        if (layout != null) {
            TextView post = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.postTextView);
            TextView time = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.postTimeTextView);

            if (post != null) {
                post.setText(layout.feedPost);
            }

            if (time != null) {
                time.setText(layout.feedTime);
            }
        }

        return view;
    }

}
```

Where I create a new array, add it to my data, and then refresh adapter:

```
FeedPostingLayout test = new FeedPostingLayout(post, currentTimePost);
        data.add(test);
        feedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add directly at `ArrayAdapter`.

For example:

```
FeedListviewAdapter adapter=new FeedListviewAdapter(ctx,id,data);
FeedPostingLayout test = new FeedPostingLayout(post, currentTimePost);
adapter.add(test);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for once try replacing the arraylist, say something like

```
setPostingLayout(ArrayList<FeedPostingLayout> postingLayout) {
    this.postingLayout = postingLayout;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Reason being the arraylist have different copies changes made to data will not be reflected to postingLayout.